# How to print 2D array to terminal window

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
```

> //Initializes Array

```
    double[][] results = new double[7][6];
```

> //Attach original methods

```
    Catapult[][] data = new Catapult[7][6];
```

> //Prints Heading

```
    printHeading();
```

> //For-loop inputs data into original methods

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
       {
           data[i][j] = new Catapult((double) (i + 5) * 5.0, (double) (j + 4) * 5.0);
           data[i][j].convertDegreesToRadians();
           data[i][j].convertMPHToMetersPerSec();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println(data[i][0] + "" + data[i][j] + "" +  data[i][j+1] + ""            + data[i][j+2] + data[i][j+3] + " " +  data[i][j+4] + " " +  data[i][j+5]);
        }
    }
```

> Whenever I try to print this, the values are null. How do I properly print the values of i and j within the 2d array?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
     {
         data[i][j] = new Catapult((double) (i + 5) * 5.0, (double) (j + 4) * 5.0);
         data[i][j].convertDegreesToRadians();
         data[i][j].convertMPHToMetersPerSec();
         System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
```

Hope that helps